# Linq Query coming back with a null value when the data is not null

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Linq query that I am using with some odd results. The query is coming back with one of the items as null, but the data in the database is not null.

```
 public void LookUpSomeInfoFromContractDetail(WorkflowHelper workflowHelper, String contractDetailId)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid _contractDetailId = workflowHelper.GuidChanger(contractDetailId);


            workflowHelper.serviceContext.ClearChanges();
            var contactDetailQuery = from ctd in workflowHelper.serviceContext.ContractDetailSet
                               where ctd.ContractDetailId.Equals(_contractDetailId)
                               select new { ctd.Title, ctd.ContractId, ctd.ContactId};
            foreach (var c in contactDetailQuery)
            {
                //logic here

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch stuff here
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the `ctd.ContactId` value comes back as null. But if I look at the same record in SQL the value is not null.

Any thoughts?

After Millie Smith's comment I checked back on both SQL and with Linq and found something interesting:

In SQL I found that there was a value that was equal to the one I was looking for:

```
select 
ctd.ContactId
,ctd.CustomerId
from ContractDetail ctd
where ctd.CustomerId = ctd.ContactId
```

returns the same number of results as:

```
select 
ctd.ContactId
,ctd.CustomerId
from ContractDetail ctd
```

Still puzzled as to why pulling `ctd.ContactId` does not show up in the Linq

Comment: Why don't you select ctd and check the values manually in the objects that are returned. See what you get. `workflowHelper.serviceContext.ContractDetailSet` is probably not returning the objects correctly.

Comment: @MillieSmith I selected all of `ctd` it is still null; For some reason that particular item is coming up as null in my linq query; though the same item `ContactId` in SQL shows a value.

Comment: Are you sure that `workflowHelper.serviceContext.ContractDetailSet` is returning the correct value in the ContactID property? I think the problem is when you pull the data from the database, not when you run it through linq.

Comment: `workflowHelper.serviceContext` is the context I am using (I have it set up in another class) and I am pulling from the `ContractDetailSet`. When I queried just the CTD object it showed the value of ContactID as null.The other values appear correct in the entire CTD object. How would I be able to tell if I was not getting the right data from the database vs from linq? A coworker who set up the same query using a SQL connection in C# and returned null as well, though her checks indicate that the record is not null in the actual db as well. It appears to be null only when we call it through C#.

Comment: I'm just saying to do `var contractDetail = workflowHelper.serviceContext.ContractDetailSet; foreach (var c in contractDetail) { Console.WriteLine(c.ContactID); }` My guess is that the ContactID will still be null. I don't know much about what ContractDetailSet is accessing, but that is probably the issue, not the Linq query.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you edited your answer.

Comment: How many total records is your LINQ query returning (`contactDetailQuery.ToList().Count();`) and how many is your SQL query returning?

Comment: @Nicknow the same number, both(The linq and SQL) return the same number of records, same values on all other fields, Linq just does not return the value for `ct.ContractId` with the Linq Query.